# Let $X ,Y \subseteq \Bbb R$ . Define $X + Y = \{x + y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$ Then Determine the conditions on $X$ and $Y$ such that $X + Y$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two subsets of $\Bbb R$. Define $X + Y = \{x + y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$
Then which of the following is/are true ?

(A) If $X$ and $Y$ are closed sets then $X + Y$  is closed?

(B) If at least of the closed sets $X$ and $Y$ is compact then $X + Y$  is compact?

I know

(1)$X + Y$ is open if either $X$ or $Y$ or both $X$ and $Y$ are open.

(2)$X$ is open if $X^c$ is closed. Where $X^c$ denotes the complement of $X$

(3)
$X$ is called open if it is neighborhood of each of its points.

(4)
$X \cup Y$ and $X \cap Y$ are open if $X$ and $Y$ are open.

(5)
$X \cup Y$ and $X \cap Y$ are closed if $X$ and $Y$ are closed.

If I take sets $X=\{ n : n=1,2,\ldots\}$ and  $Y=\{- n+{1\over n} : n= 2,3,\ldots\}$. So $X + Y = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb N\}$. Here limit point of $X + Y$ is $0$ but $0 \notin X + Y$. Hence $X + Y$ is not closed. Am I right ?

Comment: Poorly worded question. The use of 'the condition'  is wrong.'

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are closed $X+Y$ need not be closed.  If $X$ and $Y$ are are closed  and at least one of them is compact then  $X+Y$ is compact.

Comment: I have already seen the result as you said. Please provide me a detailed proof of your comment.

Comment: Try to prove these facts and someone can help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You're only correct in asserting $\{\frac1n\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \subseteq X+Y$ so it *does* hold that $0 \in \overline{X+Y}$ and $0 \notin X+Y$. So those sets do work as a counterexample, but be precise!

(B) is clearly false, find an example that is unbounded. If $X$ or $Y$ is compact and $X,Y$ are both closed it *does* hold that $X+Y$ is closed, but this requires a small argument. If $X$ and $Y$ are *both* compact, so is $X+Y$ and this is again easy to see (from continuity of addition).

Answer (score 0):

If I take sets $X=\{ n\mid n=1,2,\ldots\}$ and  $Y=\{- n+{1\over n}\mid n= 2,3,\ldots\}$. So $X + Y = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb N\}$. Here limit point of $X + Y$ is $0$ but $0 \notin X + Y$. Hence $X + Y$ is not closed.

Comment: This is false, as $X=Y$ also contains $1+\frac12 = (2 + (-1 + \frac12)$, not just the fractions converging to $0$...